How to stop the Spring batch gracefully in Spring boot application
I am using Spring batch for my spring boot application. After I schedule the job in the background, i want to stop the job.
I am using following to stop the job
jobOperator.stop(jobId)

Job is going into STOPPING state and it takes more than 1000 seconds to go into STOPPED state. I can't wait for this much time.
My configuration:

Chunk size: 50
Each record size: 10 MB
Each record time taken: 20 to 30 secs approx as i am doing S3 upload and other DB actions.

Also after i start the schedule job and do stop action. It is processing current chunk + next chunk as well instead of current chunk. I don't know what is the reason and how to avoid this.
Option 1 (tried):

When i do stop actions, I will call stopSignal.requestStop()
Then in I will get stopSignal.isStopRequested() in ItemReader. But this works for some time not all the times.

@Component
public class StopSignal {
  private boolean stopRequested = false;

  public synchronized void requestStop() {
     this.stopRequested = true;
  }

  public synchronized boolean isStopRequested() {
    return stopRequested;
  }

  public synchronized void resetStopSignal() {
    this.stopRequested = false;
  }
}

@Component
public class CustomItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T> {

    @Autowired
    private StopSignal stopSignal;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
        for (T item : items) {
            if (stopSignal.isStopRequested()) {
                // Stop processing further items in the chunk
                return;  
            }

            // Process the current item
            processItem(item);
        }
    }

    private void processItem(T item) {
        // Your logic to process the item
    }
}

Question:

How to process only current chunk when i do stop action of the job
Is there a way to stop the processing when i do stop action and process only that record (e.g 25th record in current chunk) and stop gracefully.
I have another use case, suddenly application stopped during spring batch is in processing. I have to do manual stop for step execution and job execution.

